# Prepared statement returning -2 value always

Tags: oracle, jdbc, batch-file, prepared-statement

I have a prepared statement with merge, after execution it always returns -2.

My code:

```
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("MERGE INTO EMP_BONUS EB USING (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) on (EB.EMP_id = ?) WHEN MATCHED  THEN  UPDATE SET TA =?,DA=?,TOTAL=?,MOTH=?, NAME=? WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "
        + "INSERT (EMP_ID, TA, DA, TOTAL, MOTH, NAME)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) ");



public void executes(String threadName) throws Exception {
        ConnectionPro cPro = new ConnectionPro();
        Connection connE = cPro.getConection();

        threadN = threadN + "||" + threadName;

        PreparedStatement pStmt = connE.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
        try {
            count = count + 1;

            for (Employee employeeObj : employee) {

                pStmt.setInt(1, employeeObj.getEmp_id());
            pStmt.setDouble(2, employeeObj.getSalary() * .10);
            pStmt.setDouble(3, employeeObj.getSalary() * .05);
            pStmt.setDouble(4, employeeObj.getSalary()
                    + (employeeObj.getSalary() * .05)
                    + (employeeObj.getSalary() * .10));
            pStmt.setInt(5, count);
            pStmt.setString(6, threadN);
            pStmt.setInt(7, employeeObj.getEmp_id());
            pStmt.setDouble(8, employeeObj.getSalary() * .10);
            pStmt.setDouble(9, employeeObj.getSalary() * .05);
            pStmt.setDouble(10, employeeObj.getSalary()
                    + (employeeObj.getSalary() * .05)
                    + (employeeObj.getSalary() * .10));
            pStmt.setInt(11, count);
            pStmt.setString(12, threadN);    
                pStmt.addBatch();
            }

            int arr[] = pStmt.executeBatch();

            connE.commit();

            System.out.println("Size=" + arr.length);
            if (arr.length != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i + "==" + arr[i]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             connE.rollback();
            throw e;

        } finally {

            pStmt.close();
            connE.close();

        }
    }
```

See the code the prepared statement always returning -2(all the values inside the array is -2) value for sql commands like update,merge etc., I have used library like  ojdbc6.jar,ojdbc5.jar etc

Comment: Where's the SQL statement you're trying to execute?

Comment: Kindly check it now,I had added the sql statement..

Comment: Well, I see 12 parameters that need to be specified. You're only setting 6.

Comment: Please check it now.....

Comment: It still doesn't work? What does the -2 mean?

Answer (score 3):

This is not broken.

If you read the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29 you will see that executeBatch can return the value SUCCESS_NO_INFO.

If you compare the result you get with SUCCESS_NO_INFO you'll see they are the same -- that is, SUCCESS_NO_INFO = -2.

So your code has been working all along.

Comment: Hi my intension is to identify the failed rows,and reprocess it.But SUCCESS_NO_INFO value does not help me for that.For a clear idea see my previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048338/prepared-statement-in-multithreading

Comment: Please provide a clear, *single* question demonstrating your problem. The question should provide everything we need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: And -- to clarify -- if all rows in the batch are marked as -2, then according to JDBC, all rows were succesful.